Suitable terminology for "strictly subharmonic functions"
Recall that we say a upper-semicontinuous real function $u:\Omega\subset\Bbb R^n$ to be subharmonic, if $-\Delta u\le0$ in the sense of Borel measures, or equivalently the submean value property $u(x)\le\int_{\partial B(0,1)}u(x+r\theta)dS_\theta$ holds whenever $\overline{B(x,r)}\subset\Omega$.
My question is, is there a good name for those subharmonic function $u$ which satisfies strict submean value property, i.e. $u(x)<\int_{\partial B(0,1)}u(x+r\theta)dS_\theta$ for every $r$ such that $\overline{B(x,r)}\subset\Omega$?
I would prefer to call $u$ strictly subharmonic. But in some literature, a "strictly subharmonic function" is defined to be such that $-\Delta u<0$ when $u\in C^2$.
By comparison, when we talk about convex functions, we use strictly convex for those function $u$ such that $u(\frac{x+y}2)<\frac{u(x)+u(y)}2$ for every $x\neq y$ (which is strictly sub-midpoint inequality), while $u''>0$ is refered to strongly convex.
For short I don't think the usual notion for strictly subharmonicity is good. But is there a good way to point out the version I am using for sub mean value property?
